# SQL Server data logging with delay

Tags: sql-server, sql-timestamp

I have a SCADA application linked with a SQL Server database. I have configured SCADA to save data in every minute change. Most of the time the data is logged in '00 th' second for example at time stamp '17:15:00'. Sometimes, the data gets logged in the table with '01 th' second for example at time stamp '17:30:01' instead of '17:30:00' which is desired.

What could be the cause of this one second delay?

Comment: Yes - post the same [message](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d61c7735-863a-4c9e-93b0-88b9a60426cf/sql-server-time-stamp-logging-in-tables?forum=sqldataaccess) to multiple forums independently without any cross reference so that everyone can duplicate effort and post the same questions, concerns, and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the script which logs the data is executed not instantly. It could take 1 second for example and as a result you have .01 timestamp